# Is it possible to assign the result of `calc()` to a sass/scss variable?

Tags: sass

I tried to assign the result of `calc()` to a scss variable like so:

```css
$header-height: 100px;
$max-canvas-square-size: calc(100vh - #{$header-height});

@media screen and (min-width: #{$max-canvas-square-size}) {
   // Do stuff
}
```

... but it doesn't seem to work. `$max-canvas-square-size` gets evaluated as `0px`. Is it just not permitted to save the result of a `calc()` to a variable?

Comment: Don't see any problems with your code. `$max-canvas-square-size` is `calc(100vh - 100px);`. And you can use this variable everywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to save the result of `calc()` to a Sass variable.

Sass and its variables are compiled down to CSS during development, whereas `calc()` is performed at runtime in browser. Sass variables themselves never make it into the actual stylesheet or browser, as they exist just to aid development - only their values make it to CSS.

Comment: Hi @Magnus, If this answered your question, please consider clicking the checkmark icon to the left of the answer to indicate to future readers that the question is answered.